# How to merge rows from a MySQL database table

Tags: mysql, select, merge, rows

### EDIT: I reformulated the question because it seemed too complicated the other way.

Consider the following database tables

**users**

```
#id #money
1   100
2   150
3   100
4   200
5   200
6   100
7   250
8   300
9   150
10  100
```

**merged**

```
#mainID #mergeID
1       2
1       3
```

How do I formulate a Select statement which sums the money of the merged ID's and makes a top10 list? My real database has around 100'000 id/money rows and around a hundred of merges. This means it's important to keep performance in mind.

This is what I wish to get as output in this very example:

```
#id #money
1   350    // sum of the rows with id 1,2,3 because they're merged!
8   300
7   250
4   200
5   200
9   150
6   100
10  100
```

Comment: What about adding a column to users called MergeWith and then joins would be where MergeWithID instead of on ID and use of aggregrates to get the "SUM".  The problem is going to be the Manual activity needed to identify 1,2,3 are all part of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `foreign key` column referencing the `user.pk` in your table.

Edit : I think you downvoted because I didn't make myself clear.

I am suggesting to create a *recursive relationship*. In you example you'll get :

```
select * from user ;
id | money | ref_user
1    100       1
2    150       1
3    100       1
4    200       23
5    200       11
6    100       11
```

You should be able to write an *aggregate* query like this one :

```
select sum(money) as sum_money from user group by ref_user 
    order by sum_money
    limit 10;
```

To get what you need.

Comment: I didn't vote down, that was someone else. ;) Thanks for your reply. I had something like that in mind, but then I need to update the "users" table which contains a lot of data. Please look at my first post, I reformulated the question with my idea. Maybe we'll find another way.

Comment: use ORDER BY and LIMIT 10 to select the top 10 with your query.

Comment: I wish it would be that simple, but then you don't sum up id's 1, 2, 3!

Comment: Performance should not be a problem here, relational database do that kind of job pretty well (remember what it is said about early optimization ?). The problem for you is to manually update the database whatever the solution is !

Comment: I think you can select sum(money) AS moneySum then just use ORDER BY on moneySum. Give that a try.

Comment: Yes Stan, I agree with you. I just thought it would be nicer to have the data about merged ids in another table as the data itself, because there are around 100'000 rows. If I merge 10 rows, I made a new column for 100'000 only for those 10? That's somehow not reasonable.

Comment: amiawizard: I can't follow, I'm not that advanced with queries/subqueries. Could you formulate an example?

Comment: @andreas : 1. the query is updated. 2. Don't make rule from few  exceptions. If only 0.001% of your records are concerned, maybe they are not ? What I say is : Don't build something confusing if you can solve this in cleaning your records.

Comment: Stan: The thing is, if I add a new column, I have to do that in many tables. There are several tables involved in that merge thing. It's true, not many rows will be merged in the end, but I think it would be better to use it as I described in my first post (edited version)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, I found a (dirty) way to do it directly. This is it:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  SUM(money) AS sum_money
  IFNULL(mainID, id) AS uniqueID
FROM 
  users
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  merged
ON
  id=mergeID
GROUP BY 
  uniqueID
ORDER BY 
  sum_money
LIMIT 
  10
```